# jQuery can not add Classes or remove Classes

Tags: jquery, vue.js

I using vuejs in Laravel, and in the watch action, i use Jquery.

I have noidea why hasClass is working but addClass, removeClass and toggleClass is not.

And this is my HTML code:

```js
$('#todo input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').each(function(i, elem) {
  var p = $(elem).parent().find('p');
  if (p.hasClass("checked")) {
    p.removeClass("checked");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-check d-flex flex-row pl-2 b-bottom">
  <input type="checkbox" id="sec1To0_chk_msk01" v-model="data.sec1To0_chk_msk01" class="d-none form-check-input" v-if="allow_staff" />
  <label for="sec1To0_chk_msk01" class="form-check-label d-flex pt-2">
        <div class="radio-check d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
          <span class="ni ni-check"></span>
        </div>
      </label>
  <p v-bind:class="{ checked:checked }" class="w-100 p-1 m-0">Title</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you also add HTML layout?

Comment: How do you know hasClass is working ??

Comment: Why are you using jQuery for this in the first place? Could you post the whole component you're trying to build?

Answer (score 2):

I'm  not sure, what you mean with "it is not working". so i guess the issue and provide a possible solution...

Actually, it is working. BUT - your js snippet only gets executed once, **on page load**/dom ready. i assume, that you want your `<p>` element to toggle class `checked` whenever the checkbox gets checked or unchecked.
for this, you need to bind an event trigger to your checkbox, so the js gets executed every time, you check/uncheck the box.

this will be done like that:

```
//function to execute on every click event of a checkbox
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", function(){       
    //instead of using .parent().find() you can simply use .siblings() to find the p element
    myTextElem = $(this).siblings("p");  

    // toggle the class
    myTextElem.toggleClass("checked");

    if(myTextElem.hasClass("checked")){
      // here you can do something, if it is checked
    } else {
      // here you can do something, if it is unchecked
    }
});
```

This of course only works, if the checked class and the checkbox state are kind of synced. So with the click function, as it is, your `p` element won't have the checked class onload, even when the checkbox is checked by default. 
for this, you'd need to add some code, to get executed on dom ready:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){ //loop through all checkboxes
  myTextElem = $(this).siblings("p"); //select sibling text elem
  if($(this).is(":checked")){ //if checkbox is checked
    myTextElem.addClass("checked"); //initially add class checked
  }
});
```